# Logstash container stopped because of an error creating action from filter

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

Hello I'm new to Elasticsearch

I'm working with log files comming from filebeat and logstash and I'm trying to add a field "response_time", and then affect the difference between timestamps to It.
So I create a logstash's filter and I add it to logstash configuration file but when I restared the container I get the error bellow.

**This is my logstash configuration file:**

---

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('indexDay', event.get('[@timestamp]').time.localtime('+01:00').strftime('%Y%m%d'))"
  }
  aggregate {
        add_field => {
          "response_time" => "timestamp2-timestamp1"
          }
        }
   grok {
     match => ["message","%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel},%{DATESTAMP_RFC2822:timestamp},%{NOTSPACE:event_type},%{NUMBER:capture_res_id},%{NUMBER:capture_pid},%{NUMBER:mti},%{NUMBER:node_id}
    ,%{UUID:msg_uuid},%{NOTSPACE:module},%{NUMBER :respCode}"]}
    if [event_type] == "request_inc" {
     aggregate {
       msg_uuid => "%{UUID}"
       timestamp1 => event.get('DATESTAMP_RFC2822')
       code => "map['response_time'] = 0"
       map_action => "create"
     }
   }
   if [event_type] == "response_outg" {
     aggregate {
       msg_uuid => "%{UUID}"
       event_type => event.set('event_type')
       timestamp2 => "%{DATESTAMP_RFC2822}"
       code => "map['response_time']"
       map_action => "update"
       end_of_task => true
       timeout =>120
     }
   }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    template => "/usr/share/logstash/templates/testblogstash.template.json"
    template_name => "testblogstash"
    template_overwrite => true
    index => "testblogstash-%{indexDay}"
    codec => json
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

And this is an exemple of my log file:

```
{"log_level":"INFO","timestamp":"2021-12-15T16:06:24.400087Z","event_type":"s_tart","ca_id":"11","c_pid":"114","mti":"00","node_id":"00","msg_uuid":"1234","module":"cmde"}
{"log_level":"INFO","timestamp":"2021-12-15T16:06:31.993057Z","event_type":"e_nd","mti":"00","node_id":"00","msg_uuid":"1234","module":"PWC-cmde","respCode":"1"}
```

This is the error from docker logs :

> [2022-06-01T14:43:24,529][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute
> action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
> :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
> [A-Za-z0-9_-], [ \t\r\n], "#", "{", [A-Za-z0-9_], "}" at line
> 25, column 24 (byte 689) after filter {\r\n json {\r\n source =>
> "message"\r\n }\r\n ruby {\r\n code => "event.set('indexDay',
> event.get('[@timestamp]').time.localtime('+01:00').strftime('%Y%m%d'))"\r\n
> }\r\n aggregate {\r\n add_field => {\r\n "response_time" =>
> "timestamp2-timestamp1"\r\n\t\t }\r\n\t\t}\r\n grok {\r\n match =>
> ["message","%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel},%{DATESTAMP_RFC2822:timestamp},%{NOTSPACE:event_type},%{NUMBER:capture_res_id},%{NUMBER:capture_pid},%{NUMBER:mti},%{NUMBER:node_id}\r\n\t,%{UUID:msg_uuid},%{NOTSPACE:module},%{NUMBER
> :respCode}"]}\r\n if [event_type] == "request_inc" {\r\n aggregate
> {\r\n\t msg_uuid => "%{UUID}"\r\n\t timestamp1 => event",
> :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in
> `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:187:in` initialize'",
> "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in` initialize'",
> "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in
> `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:383:in` block
> in converge_state'"]}
>
> ...

> [2022-06-01T14:43:29,460][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.

Comment: if your log already in `json` format then there is no meaning to use `grok` pattern and insted you can use `json` filter.

Comment: I change grok to json but the error still persist

Comment: `I run it on Grok Debugger` by this do you mean you have run above configuration from Kibana Grok Debugger ? If you are doing this then it will never work because you can just test grok pattern from there and not entire configuration of logstash or filebeat.

Comment: Yes sir that's what I mean, so now to test I need to update the configuration of logstash and restart the container ?

Comment: Yes, and please post the error stacktrace from log file here once you done it. Also, `"timestamp2-timestamp1"` this will not work because each filter is executed seperatly for each log event so you can not persiste value of last event of last log line.

Comment: can you please edit your question and add error from log into question itself insted of putting into comment.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).